# Types in storage containing (nested) mappings cannot be assigned to

Tags: solidity, remix

i have set wallet address that only owner can change, but i can not read the wallet address. my view functions giving me this error

here is the code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


contract NFT {
    uint256 public fauouRiteNum;
    
    mapping(address => address) private wallet;
    
    
     
    function setNumber(uint256 _fav) public returns(uint256){
        return fauouRiteNum=_fav;
    }
    
    function marketing(address _add) public returns(address){
         wallet[msg.sender] = _add;
    }
    
    function getWallet(uint256 _wallet) public view returns(uint256){
    return wallet=_wallet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t be a mapping from address to address ? And not from address to number ?

Comment: i did change it to address to address but it gives me 0*00000 address while i add a full address !

Comment: What gives you 0x000000…? How are u calling it ?

Comment: i am setting the address: plz try this on remix, you will know

Comment: how can i read the set marketing wallet address? my view function gives me error

Comment: I don't know why you want to return a "uint256" :)? uint256 is only for numbers, and you are asking for address ... anyway good luck, solidity is not easy and need you to understand the very basics otherwise your contracts will have bugs and security risks

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract NFT {
    uint256 public fauouRiteNum;
  
    mapping(address => address) private wallet;
     
    function setNumber(uint256 _fav) public returns(uint256) {
        return fauouRiteNum=_fav;
    }
    
    function marketing(address _add) public {
         wallet[msg.sender] = _add;
    }
    
    function getWallet() public view returns(address) {
        return wallet[msg.sender];
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello, can you plz take a look here. the transfer functionality is not working.    `(https://github.com/coderbang1/transfer-token/tree/main)

Comment: @stofu sorry no time and experience to read a complex contract , if u have another question please post it and maybe someone could help

Comment: can you solve this one:  CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.

Comment: @stofu https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack+too+deep there are many reasons for this problem. try to find one of the solution from other questions about it